# the acknowledgment that **extenuating circumstances** affect our daily work

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "the acknowledgment" as the "impact statements", or part of them. Am I on the right track?

> Science Magazine just tweeted:

"Why did it take a global pandemic for everyone to realize the benefit of impact statements even in the best of times? #COVID19 is new, but **the acknowledgment that **extenuating circumstances** affect our daily work** and career paths is not."

[Source](https://twitter.com/ScienceMagazine/status/1401781017850097668)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be quite honest the tweet is very confusing and I would suggest badly worded.

Take the statement

> "Why did it take a global pandemic....... for everyone to realize the benefit of impact statements..... even in the best of times?"

***at this point I expected to see a statement of what happens***/happened in the best of times. For example

> "Why did it take a global pandemic for everyone to realize the benefit of impact statements even in the best of times **we need to be judged less harshly when external influences intrude into our lives**?  #COVID19 is new.......blah blah.

***But it never happened*** Such that now this tweet directly places a **Global pandemic as causing a "Best time"????** In who's life may I ask?

*surely, even if it did not take the form of my earlier suggestion. Then the statement should have been redacted in favour of;

> Why did it take a global pandemic for everyone to realize the benefit of impact statements?
> #COVID19 is new, but the acknowledgment ......

**Further more!** The relationship between

> benefit of impact statements

And

> the acknowledgment that extenuating circumstances affect our daily work and career paths is not (new)."

Is confounding, ***if the acknowledgment is not new what is the benefit being offered by the impact statements***? It has no mention here?

---

However ***may it be, that I am under estimating the integrity of the author*** in which instance I unreservedly apologise.

possibly the errors are less grand. Let us try a less hurried tweet!

> "Why did it take a global pandemic for everyone to realize the benefit of impact statements?**.......** #COVID19 is new, but the **need,** ***even in the best of times***, to acknowledge, that extenuating circumstances affect our daily work and career paths is not."

Comment: Thank you. That is a good guess, at least I've got a handle on the tweet because of your hard work.